# I need to identify the last child of list of groups which have parents-child relationship.

Tags: sql, joomla

I have a website with groups of members. Groups are organised in country group, region group, subregion group and city group.

city group is child of subregion group, 
subregion group is child of region group
region group is child of country group
coutnry group is child of nothing (parent=0).

These groups have a field category (plumber, furniture, mechanic,etc...)

Let's say the member David join the group "Plumber". He has also to select his city in the form (ex:he selected Los Angeles).

Our script add him in these 4 groups:

Plumber Los Angeles city center
Plumber Los Angeles
Plumber California
Plumber USA

You can find the table users and the table groups attached as images.

[image]

[image]

MY QUESTIONS:
I need an SQL command to count the quantity of users for a city group

I need to identify quickly the id of the city group which a member has joined.
Example: David join Los angeles plumber groups, what is the SQL command to identify the last child of the groups.

I hope I was clear enough. I hope some SQL genius will be kind enough to find me the solution because my brain smoked too much :-(

Answer (score 1):

IF you have a true nested structure you should really use a nested table with lft, rgt, path and level columns and extend JTableNested for your table class. Then use the standard methods it provides for getting the paths, number of children and so on. Then putting someone in a city will put that person in everything up that branch.  Can a user only be in exactly 1 city or in several? TBH you can just clone the tags table or really, just use tags period since they support nesting. Or you can just use categories if user:city is a 1:1 relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is quite confusing, but I think this might help.

The SQL Statement for this part "I need an SQL command to count the quantity of users for a city group" would be similar to the following:

```
SELECT group, COUNT(*) AS QtyOfUsers FROM [Table users] GROUP BY group
```

For this part of your question "I need to identify quickly the id of the city group which a member has joined. Example: David join Los angeles plumber groups, what is the SQL command to identify the last child of the groups", the SQL Statement will be similar to the following:

```
SELECT category, user_id, MAX(id) AS LatestRecordAdded FROM [table groups] GROUP BY category, user_id
```